# StreamReader cannot read files with "#" in their name

Tags: c#, ftp, streamreader, ftpwebrequest

I'm using this code to read files from ftp server:

```
static List<String> GetDirectory(String DirectoryName)
    {
        try
        {
            var ConnectionString = String.Format("{0}/{1}", Connection.GetFTPConfig.FTPSourceAddress, DirectoryName);
            var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConnectionString);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Connection.GetFTPConfig.FTPSourceUsername, Connection.GetFTPConfig.FTPSourcePassword);

            var Directories = new List<String>();
            var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    Directories.Add(line);
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            response.Close();
            return Directories;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<String>();
        }
    }
```

`DirectoryName` is the address of my folder, and I want to read all files in this folder.
This code always works fine, But when `DirectoryName` contains `"#"`, this line
`string line = streamReader.ReadLine();` returns null.

I checked the `streamReader`. Before `ReadLine()`, the value of `streamReader.EndOfStream` is **True**. But after that, the value of `streamReader.EndOfStream` changes to:
**'streamReader.EndOfStream' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'**

When I change the folder name it works fine. For example, my folder name is `"2014-06-18_06-58-47-529_14#42411-R"` and the file name in the folder is `"2014-06-18_06-58-47-529_14#42411-R.jpg"`. When I change the # in the folder name, to `"2014-06-18_06-58-47-529_14142411-R"`, it works fine and return the list of files in the folder!
What's the problem?

Comment: I very much doubt that this has anything to do with `StreamReader`. I suspect this is more a matter of the FTP server not finding the files.  I suggest you look at what's being returned on the wire, e.g. with Wireshark.

Comment: @sloth I waste so much time to search for this problem but never seen this question before. thank you.

Comment: @SoheilaHg First google hit for `c# ftp special character name`

Comment: @sloth it's never came to my mind to google `special character name`. I always searched for `# in file name`.